# Form GET key square brackets encoded upon form submission

Tags: php, html, forms, nginx, url-encoding

When I submit my form my square brackets end up encoded in the url like this:
`http://example.com/myurl?key%5B%5D=something`

I'm checking the nginx `access.log` to see if I can see anything weird in there, but it's just the same, single request that's logged for `http://example.com/myurl?key%5B%5D=something` as well (which makes me think no rewriting is causing this).

What else could be causing this? Can't say I've ever had this happening before.

Tested this in both chrome and Edge, both same result.

Comment: Can you post the form please?

Comment: The browser probably did it and its normal

Comment: @EdsonHoracioJunior the form isnt anything special, just the usual `<form method="GET" href="#"><select name="mykey[]" multiple="multiple"></select></form>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What else could be causing this?

The browser.

From [the HTML spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#url-encoded-form-data):

> If the byte is in the range 0x2A, 0x2D, 0x2E, 0x30 to 0x39, 0x41 to 0x5A, > 0x5F, 0x61 to 0x7A
>   **Leave the byte as is**.

`[` and `]` are `U+005B : LEFT SQUARE BRACKET` and `U+005D : RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET`, so they aren't in that range.

> Otherwise
>
> 1. Let s be a string consisting of a U+0025 PERCENT SIGN character (%) followed by uppercase ASCII hex digits representing the hexadecimal
>      value of the byte in question (zero-padded if necessary).
> 2. Encode the string s as US-ASCII, so that it is now a byte string.
> 3. Replace the byte in question in the name or value being processed by the bytes in s, preserving their relative order.

So they get replaced by `%5B` and `%5D`

Comment: @xorinzor — Why? Do you expect many websites to be using form data parsing libraries that can't handle the common standards for encoding form data? You tagged this question [tag:php]. PHP will decode them correctly when parsing the data to populate `$_GET` and `$_POST`.

Comment: I've never had this issue in chrome before that when posting an array of GET inputs it would encode the square brackets. And what I'm noticing so far is that Symfony doesn't decode the keys either. They're being treated as-is.
(Also: see edit)

Comment: I figured it out, not sure if I'm just remembering how I used to do this incorrectly or if this has actually changed somewhere along the way